# 'ResolvedOutputS3Uri' key missing from describe_feature_group() dict

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I'm having this issue when describing a feature group from a pipeline script.

The dictionary retrieved by describe_feature_group() doesn't have the 'ResolvedOutputS3Uri' key and I'm trying to figure out why. The feature group exists and has data (actually, the description works perfectly fine from a SageMaker notebook)

Anyone have a hint on where to start looking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is the feature group enabled for offline storage? You can [verify](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/feature-store-use-with-studio.html#feature-store-view-feature-group-detail-studio) it from SageMaker Studio.